# How to add SKU in the attribute list in the More Information tab of the product view page?

Tags: product, product-attribute, product-view, sku, product-tab

I have added the following code to catalog_product_view.xml to show the SKU in the list of attributes inside the "More information" tab

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
  <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
      </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceBlock>
```

The other customizations in the file are visible, but not this one. Any idea?

Comment: did you tried this? let me know if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do anything like that

You just follow below step to display sku in **More Information** tab on product view page

1. Go to Stores -> Attributes -> Product

[image]

2. Search **SKU** attribute and edit it

[image]

3. Go to **Storefront Properties** tab and change **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** value from **No** to **Yes**

[image]

**Result :**

[image]

Note : Flush cache and check

Hope this will help you

Comment: thank you! it works!